# Get a value from an object and use that value to fill up other keys in that same object under a condition

Tags: javascript, object

So here's an example:

```
{
    "part": "Intro",
    "e": "------5/6------8\\6-|-------------------|-------------------",
    "B": "-----------9-------|---------6p8---(6)-|-------------------",
    "G": "--8----------------|---8h9-------------|--<8>--------------",
    "D": "",
    "A": "",
    "E": "",
    "endMsg": "Continue..."
}
```

**Note:** The *double*-slash will turn into *one* slash only upon render of text.

1. I want to get value from this object that is not empty. (So that could be from the `e` key or from the `B` key. As long it's not empty.)
2. Then I'm replacing that value using this expression here:

   str.replace(/[0-9-. a-zA-Z // \ ~ ( ) < >]/g, '-');

It's for replacing the numbers, letters, and other characters into dashes.

3. I want to use that value with the dashes and pipe chars only to fill up the other keys inside the same object that are empty.
4. In the end, I want it to look something like this:

> ```
> {
>    "part": "Intro",
>    "e": "------5/6------8\\6-|-------------------|-------------------",
>    "B": "-----------9-------|---------6p8---(6)-|-------------------",
>    "G": "--8----------------|---8h9-------------|--<8>--------------",
>    "D": "-------------------|-------------------|-------------------",
>    "A": "-------------------|-------------------|-------------------",
>    "E": "-------------------|-------------------|-------------------",
>    "endMsg": "Continue..."
> }
> ```

I have no idea how to achieve this in code. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over each key value pair and replace the value if its empty. Be aware that a backslash is used for escaping a character. To fix this we first replace the backslashes with dashes and then replace the rest.

The regex could also be simplified to `/[^-|]/g` which means replace all symbols except `-` and `|`

```js
const lines = {
    "part": "Intro",
    "e": "------5/6-----8\\6-|-------------------|-------------------",
    "B": "-----------9-------|---------6p8---(6)-|-------------------",
    "G": "--8----------------|---8h9-------------|--<8>--------------",
    "D": "",
    "A": "",
    "E": "",
    "endMsg": "Continue..."
};

const createFullLines = (lines, blacklist = ['part', 'endMsg']) => {
  // Find a line that is not empty
  const line = Object.entries(lines).find(([key, line]) => {
    return !blacklist.includes(key) && line.trim();
  });
  
  // Exit if all lines are empty
  if(!line) return lines;
  
  // Destructure to get only value
  const [_, filledLine] = line;
  
  // Create new line with only dashes
  const newLine = filledLine.replace(/[^-|]/g, '-');
  
  // Update lines
  for(const key in lines) {
    lines[key] ||= newLine;
  }
  
  return lines;
}

const result = createFullLines(lines);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Zedd, this can easily be solved by supplying a list of keys that should be skipped in our case a `blacklist`. All keys with those names will be skipped. See updated snippet

Comment: I actually came up with a solution for this issue about the `part` & `endMsg` keys before you updated your answer @Reyno: `const filledLine = Object.values(newTab).find((line) => { if (/^[(a-zA-Z /\s/)]+$/.test(line)) return; return line.trim(); });` This works because I know that these keys only contain letters, (), & spaces. But I still used your solution for it is safer and I can be more flexible with the value of these keys. Upvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should just iterate between your object's keys like this:

```js
// find first non-empty field, !! - conversion to boolean
let nonEmptyKey = Object.keys(obj).find(key => !!obj[key]);

for(let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  // check if value is empty
  if(!obj[key]) {
    obj[key] = obj[nonEmptyKey].replace(/[0-9-. a-zA-Z // \ ~ ( ) < >]/g, '-');
  }
}
```

Also, you can simplify your regex to this:

```js
// replace all symbols except - and |
str.replace(/[^-|]/g, '-');
```